# removing last record comma

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I want to remove the last record comma from fetched value. I used `$album1 = substr($album,0,-1);` to remove last character comma from the value  `$ album'.  I caught:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,'

Whats wrong with this in `substr()`?

```
$album = {"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/video","pic_id":"kg5k4"},

while($fet_pic=mysql_fetch_array($albpic)) {  
    $album.=$fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'].',';
}

$album1 = substr($album,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

use PHP `rtrim` Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

```
rtrim($album, ",")
```

Full code

```
<?php 
$album = '{"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/video","pic_id":"kg5k4"},';

         echo rtrim($album, ",");
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/474872)

Comment: my $album={"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/png","pic_id":"zhadb"},
         {"media_type":"image/video","pic_id":"kg5k4"},

Comment: is any other solution to do

Answer (score 0):

you can uses `trim` to remove last comma from the string

like this

```
$album1 = trim($album, ',');
```

Comment: rtrim or trim. both should work

Comment: still having problem

Comment: where is it causing problem? check the line number and whether that issue is same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code :

```
$rows = array();
while($fet_pic=mysql_fetch_array($albpic))
{  
    $rows[] = $fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'];
}
$album = implod(", ",$rows);
```